# Substring to Int C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a string that is only 1s and 0s to a decimal value. The variable `value` is initialized to 0 and is never updated. I suspect the problem is that `binaryString[i]` is treated as a string and therefore the athematic function doesn't work. How can I fix this?

```
void binaryToDec(string binaryString, int value)
{
  int binaryStringLength = binaryString.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < binaryStringLength; i++)
    {
      value += pow(2,i)+ binaryString[i];
    }
}
```

I tried to use basic type casting like `int(binaryString[i])` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly `binaryString[i]` is a character, not an integer. To convert a digit character to an integer you can just subtract `'0'`.

```
binaryString[i] - '0'
```

Secondly `pow(2,i)` returns a floating point number, when you want an integer. This is inefficient, and even more seriously might be subject to rounding errors. Instead you should use a shift operator, which  efficiently and accurately calculates integer powers of two.

```
1 << i
```

Thirdly you have `+` where you need `*`. The two terms should be multiplied not added.

Putting all that together you get

```
value += (1 << i) * (binaryString[i] - '0');
```

But the most serious error of all is that your function does not return a value. It should look like this

```
int binaryToDec(string binaryString)
{
    int value = 0;
    ...
    return value;
}
```

Your version passes `value` as a parameter, that's the wrong way round, `binaryString` is a parameter, but `value` should be **returned** from the function. Not sure why but this is a difference a lot of newbies struggle with.

Comment: One caveat with the bit shift (or multiplication for that matter) is you have to use a type large enough to represent the string. If the string is 48 binary digits long, you need a type at least 48 bits long. Typically an `int` is only 32 bits, and if you run out of space the results are usually predictable--two's compliment  overflow--but technically either undefined or unspecified behaviour. The rules changed recently and I'm not 100% sure exactly how it washed out, but either way you almost certainly get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a bitset from the string and then back to a `ullong`.

But, limiting the solution to a maximum binary string size.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/qce31ahhv)

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <stdexcept>  // out_of_range

auto binaryToDec(const std::string& binary) {
    if (binary.size() > 64) {
        throw std::out_of_range{ "binary string is too big" };
    }
    return std::bitset<64>{binary}.to_ullong();
}

int main() {
    try {
        std::string binary_1{"101010"};
        fmt::print("binary: {}, decimal: {}\n", binary_1, binaryToDec(binary_1));
        std::string binary_2{
            "1111""1111""1111""1111"
            "1111""1111""1111""1111"
            "1111""1111""1111""1111"
            "1111""1111""1111""1111"
            "1"
        };
        fmt::print("{}\n", binaryToDec(binary_2));
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        fmt::print("Error: {}.\n", e.what());
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   binary: 101010, decimal: 42
//   Error: binary string is too big.
```